# Can't parse this xml properly in php

Tags: php, xml

I'm getting an xml string from another website as $data, then

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($xml);
```

Gives:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 1.33 )
[Session] => SimpleXMLElement Object
( [Key] => f42d3a9ca4203197750736070171084d
[Count] => 1513
[SubExp] => Sun Mar 27 00:00:00 2016
[GMTime] => Wed Dec 3 19:32:48 2014
[Remark] => cpu: 0.022s ) ) 

echo $xml['version'];
```

Gives 1.33

```
echo $xml['Key'];
echo $xml->Key;
```

Both come back empty.  So how can I get at the value for the Key tag?
It almost looks like a nested array but I tried that and no results either.
Any ideas as to how to do this?  Help appreciated!

Comment: A `print_r` dump uses indentation to visualize the actual structure. Use your browsers view source, or wrap it in `<pre>` tags if you're not using a terminal.

Comment: It looks like Key belongs to the Session object. Have you tried:

`$xml['Session']->Key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$xml` is an object, `session` is an object property that holds an object and `key` is a property of that object:

```
echo $xml->session->key;
```